# Powershell extract string start with

Tags: powershell

I have a txt file with following content:

```
testdemo | 5 | 4563456| OMNI | retailomni
testRetail | 142 | 3453456345| testRetai111l | test
testtesttest | 44 | 4564356| apl | APL
```

I need to select whole string, that starts from "testdemo". How this can be done in PS?

```
$operator = "testdemo"
$operatorcontent = Get-Content operators.txt | "Need to get whole string, starts from $operator"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Select-String` cmdlet.

```
Get-Content operators.txt | Select-String -Pattern "testdemo"
```

More about `Select-String` --> `Get-Help Select-String -Online`

Answer (score 9):

```
    Get-Content operators.txt | Select-String -Pattern "testdemo"
```

Will select if the line contains **testdemo** anywhere in the line

If you want to select lines that  that starts with **testdemo**

```
    Get-Content operators.txt | Select-String -Pattern "^testdemo"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Get-Content operators.txt | ForEach-Object {
    if($_ -match "testdemo"){
        $_
    }
}
```